# Zend DB Selecting constants - columns that do not exist in table

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table, zend-db-select

I'm trying to do this query using Zend DB select but I'm not able to do so

This is the sql query

```
select shopping_id,shopping_details,"friend" as type
from shopping
```

Notice here how I'm specifying "friend" as type and friend is not a column in the shopping table.

Now how do I do this in Zend. I have tried this but it gives me an error saying "sh.friend Column does not exist"

```
$select->from(array('sh'=>'shopping'),array('shopping_id','shopping_details','"friend" as type');
```

Any help will be appreciated 
thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try with `Zend_Db_Expr`, maybe something like:

```
$select->from(array('sh'=>'shopping'),
    array('shopping_id','shopping_details',
         new Zend_Db_Expr('"friend" as type'));
```

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$select->from(
    array('sh'=>'shopping'),
    array('shopping_id','shopping_details','friend'=>'type', 'alias'=>'column or expression')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Zend Framework 2/3 or Laminas you have to use `Laminas\Db\Sql\Expression`. Make sure to quote your constant with a double-quote `""`.

```php
$select->from(['e' => 'experience'])
    ->columns([
        'id' => 'id',
        'value' => 'title',
        'name' => new Laminas\Db\Sql\Expression('"skill"')
    ]);
```

*for Zend Framework the name of the expression class is `Zend\Db\Sql\Expression`.