# How do I add column to select statement in ZF2?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying to add a column in zf2 to a select statement.  Similar to the below link (but below only seems to work for ZF1).  Is there a way to do this in zf2?

[Zend DB Selecting constants - columns that do not exist in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305470/zend-db-selecting-constants-columns-that-do-not-exist-in-table)

Below is what I tried:

```
$select->columns("foo" => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('"foo" as type'))
```

The SQL Query looks like this:

```
select *, 'foo'  from bar
```

Where foo is the value and name of column for all results. Trying the above I get `"Unknown column 'foo' in 'field list'"`

Many Thanks,
M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming `type` is the alias:

try this:

```
$select->columns(array("type" => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("'foo'")));
```

Answer (score 4):

Problem is that the method `$select->columns()` overwrites the existing columns.

To counter this problem, you can extend your own "select" and add a new method to "add" columns (as the columns property of the Select class is protected).

Example;

**CustomSelect.php**

```
class CustomSelect extends \Zend\Db\Sql\Select
{
    /**
     * @param array $columns
     * @param bool $prefixColumnsWithTable
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addColumns(array $columns, $prefixColumnsWithTable = true) {
        $this->columns = $this->columns + $columns;
        $this->prefixColumnsWithTable = (bool) $prefixColumnsWithTable;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$select = new CustomSelect();
$select->addColumns(['type' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("'foo'")]);
$select->addColumns(['*']); //This is the default value though - so adding after adding shouldn't be nessecary (except if you've used "columns()" before)
```